# Simple Python Regex to separate the words

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Image link [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHPVT.jpg).
I have the following router output:

```
config t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
n7k(config)# port-profile demo_ethernet
n7k(config-port-prof)# ?
  bandwidth       Set bandwidth informational parameter
  beacon          Disable/enable the beacon for an interface
  cdp             Configure CDP interface parameters
  channel-group   Configure port channel parameters
  delay           Specify interface throughput delay
  description     Enter port-profile description of maximum 80 characters
```

From the above output, I want this:

```
['bandwidth' , 'beacon' , 'cdp' , 'channel-group' , 'delay' , 'description']
```

I am trying

```
m = re.compile('(\w+\s\w+)')
n = m.findall(buffer)
```

And getting this output:

```
['config t', 'Enter configuration', 'one per', 'End with', 'profile demo_ethernet', 'Set bandwidth', 'informational parameter', 'enable the', 'beacon for', 'an interface', 'Configure CDP', 'interface parameters', 'Configure port', 'channel parameters', 'Specify interface', 'throughput delay', 'Enter port', 'profile description', 'of maximum', '80 characters']
```

Comment: What's the rule for matching ?

Comment: I want the left side keys. and after first four lines.

Comment: Please format your data properly. It appears as one long string.

Comment: 1st line-config t
2nd line-Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
3rd line-n7k(config)# port-profile demo_ethernet
4th line-n7k(config-port-prof)# ?
5th-bandwidth       Set bandwidth informational parameter
6th-beacon          Disable/enable the beacon for an interface
 7th-cdp             Configure CDP interface parameters
 8th- channel-group   Configure port channel parameters
 9th- delay           Specify interface throughput delay
 10th-description     Enter port-profile description of maximum 80       characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should work (assuming whatever line you want to match have space in starting)

```
^\s+([\w-]+)\s+.+$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rB0pI7/1)**

*Python code* (For simplicity I have taken all input in a single string)

```
p = re.compile(r'^\s+([\w-]+)\s+.+$', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "config t\nEnter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.\nn7k(config)# port-profile demo_ethernet\nn7k(config-port-prof)# ?\n  bandwidth       Set bandwidth informational parameter\n  beacon          Disable/enable the beacon for an interface\n  cdp             Configure CDP interface parameters\n  channel-group   Configure port channel parameters\n  delay           Specify interface throughput delay\n  description     Enter port-profile description of maximum 80 characters"

print(re.findall(p, test_str))
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/c17BO6)**

Comment: @ursandy Does this `regex` meets your requirement?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. @rock321987.

Comment: Accepted.
But why my question is rated as -1?

Comment: OK. Thank you @rock321987. :)